What properties do these "norm-equal" polynomials have?
Let us first define the "norm-equal" polynomials :
For $f(x),g(x)\in \mathbb{C}[x]$, if $\forall z\in \mathbb{C},|z|=1$, we have $|f(z)|=|g(z)|$, then we call $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are "norm-equal".
I have tried using the Mobius transformation (or linear fractional transformation), but few results came out.
I guess there exist $z_{0} \in \mathbb{C},|z_{0}|=1$, such that $f(x)=z_{0}\cdot g(x)$ or $f(x)=z_{0}\cdot g(\frac{1}{x})$.
Is it correct in all circumstances? What if $f(x),g(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]$? If not, what properties hold all the time?

Hi, you forgot another obvious transformation, namely multiplying by a power of $x$. Squaring your condition it is equivalent to look at $|f(z)|^2 = f(z) \bar{f}{rec}(z)$ where $\bar{f}{rec}$ is the conjugate reciprocal polynomial. Now by Fourier theory your condition is equivalent to $f \bar{f}{rec} = g \bar{g}{rec}$, which is an equality between two polynomials, so you can look at leading coefficient and roots, etc.

this is absolutely not true as one can see from the simple example $f(z)=2z-1$ and $g(z)=z-2$ as when $|z|=1$ one has $\bar z =1/z$ so $|f(z)|=|f(\bar z)|=|2/z-1|=|z-2|=g(z)|$
